# Не отрабатывает nginx сервер в докере

Tags: php, nginx, docker

Создал новый докер контейнер с php8, composer, nginx.

Запускаю docker-compose up. Всё отрабатывает корректно и без ошибок.
Но когда перехожу на localhost:1025 (У меня указан этот порт), ничего нет. Как будто на этом порту ничего нет.

В чём может быть причина?

Структура проекта:

[image: Структура проекта]

docker-compose.yaml:

[image: docker-compose.yaml]

default.conf:

```
server {
listen 80;
index index.php index.html;
server_name localhost;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
root /var/www/html;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

}

Comment: Изучайте логи ...